# Serializing groovy map to string with quotes

Tags: serialization, groovy, deserialization

I'm trying to persist a groovy map to a file. My current attempt is to write the string representation out and then read it back in and call `evaluate` on it to recreate the map when I'm ready to use it again.

The problem I'm having is that the `toString()` method of the map removes vital quotes from the values of the elements. When my code calls evaluate, it complains about an unknown identifier.

This code demonstrates the problem:

```
m = [a: 123, b: 'test']
print "orig: $m\n"

s = m.toString()
print " str: $s\n"

m2 = evaluate(s)
print " new: ${m2}\n"
```

The first two print statements almost work -- but the quotes around the value for the key `b` are gone. Instead of showing `[a: 123, b: 'test']`, it shows `[a: 123, b: test]`.

At this point the damage is done. The `evaluate` call chokes when it tries to evaluate `test` as an identifier and not a string.

So, my specific questions:

1. Is there a better way to serialize/de-serialize maps in Groovy?
2. Is there a way to produce a string representation of a map with proper quotes?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Groovy provides the [`inspect()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#inspect()) method returns an object as a parseable string:

```
// serialize
def m = [a: 123, b: 'test']
def str = m.inspect()

// deserialize
m = Eval.me(str)
```

Another way to serialize a groovy map as a readable string is with JSON:

```
// serialize
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
def m = [a: 123, b: 'test']
def builder = new JsonBuilder()
builder(m)
println builder.toString()

// deserialize
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
m = slurper.parseText('{"a": 123, "b": "test"}')
```

Comment: add def's for people cutting and pasting ;)

Comment: `.inspect()` is extremely helpful for debugging code and pulling example maps out into unit tests. I see many upvotes in your future.

Comment: It looks like `.inspect` requires a security approval.  `Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods inspect java.lang.Object.`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `myMap.toMapString()`