# Map to String/String to Map conversion in Groovy

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I have a json object that gets passed into a save function as

```
{
  "markings": {
      "headMarkings": "Brindle",
      "leftForeMarkings": "",
      "rightForeMarkings": "sock",
      "leftHindMarkings": "sock",
      "rightHindMarkings": "",
      "otherMarkings": ""
}
```

** EDIT **

The system parses it and passes it to my function as a mapping. I don't actually have the JSON, although it wouldn't be difficult to build up the JSON myself, it just seems like overkill

*** END EDIT **

The `toString()` function ends up putting the results into the database as

```
"[rightForeMarkings:, otherMarkings:, leftForeMarkings:sock, leftHindMarkings:sock, rightHindMarkings:, headMarkings:brindle]"
```

I then want to save that as a string (fairly easy) by calling

```
params.markings.toString()
```

From here, I save the info and return the updated information.

My issue is that since I am storing the object in the DB as a string, I can't seem to get the markings back out as a map (to then be converted to JSON).

I have tried a few different things to no avail, although it is completely possible that I went about something incorrectlywith these...

```
Eval.me(Item.markings)
evaluate(Item.markings)
Item.markings.toList()
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You can use `JsonSlurper`. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14268118/2051952) should help.

Comment: JsonSlurper may work. It's not the ideal solution for our implementation, but I think I will give it a go and let you know what ends up happening.

Comment: Looks like you are not persisting the string appropriately. I am testing few things for you, will let you know the results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Throwing my tests.

Using JSON converters in Grails, I think this should be the approach: (synonymous to @JamesKleeh and @GrailsGuy)

```
def json = '''{
                  "markings": {
                      "headMarkings": "Brindle",
                      "leftForeMarkings": "",
                      "rightForeMarkings": "sock",
                      "leftHindMarkings": "sock",
                      "rightHindMarkings": "",
                      "otherMarkings": ""
                   }
                }'''

def jsonObj = grails.converters.JSON.parse(json)
//This is your JSON object that should be passed in to the method
print jsonObj //[markings:[rightForeMarkings:sock, otherMarkings:, leftForeMarkings:, leftHindMarkings:sock, rightHindMarkings:, headMarkings:Brindle]]

def jsonStr = jsonObj.toString()
//This is the string which should be persisted in db
assert jsonStr == '{"markings":{"rightForeMarkings":"sock","otherMarkings":"","leftForeMarkings":"","leftHindMarkings":"sock","rightHindMarkings":"","headMarkings":"Brindle"}}'

//Get back json obj from json str
def getBackJsobObj = grails.converters.JSON.parse(jsonStr)
assert getBackJsobObj.markings.leftHindMarkings == 'sock'
```

Comment: toString() doesn't give me back the same string that you have as your jsonStr. It is the same as jsonObj. Also, it gets passed to my function as a params that are mapped. The system converts it on the way in before it hits my function.

Comment: From where do you get your base json object which gets passed to method? Do you have a json string or an object initially, before applying any kind of logic? @DavidZiemann

Comment: I have an object. My apologies. I should have made that apparent in my initial question. If I log out markings it is the same as your jsonObj. It looks like I was able to get yours working (still doing a bit of testing). I'll let you know the results :)

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive result. It worked extremely well. I had to modify it a hair, but this is due to the architecture of our system and not your code.

Comment: @DavidZiemann Glad it helped. I was just guiding on holding the bow and arrow, bulls eye was indicated by JamesKleeh and GrailsGuy. ;-)

Comment: I still seem to be having some issues due to the jsonObj not actually displaying in the way you said above. It still displays with the JSON format rather than the map. This causes my object to assume it is a string and render it as such, although that might be a separate question to ask.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, you want to convert a String to a JSON object?  You can actually bypass converting it to a map, and parse it directly as a JSON object:

```
import grails.converters.JSON

def json = JSON.parse(Item.markings)
```

This will give you your entire JSON object, and then you can just reference the values as you would a map.

Comment: I call `render Item as JSON` when I return the data. I assume that does the same thing as `JSON.parse(Item)`, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @DavidZiemann Yeah they're pretty similar, but you're not actually trying to render the JSON, right?  Just get a reference to it?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure the difference. it's part of an API, and I wrap it in a withFormat{JSON{}} syntax. I'm fairly new to grails/groovy if you couldn't tell :)

Comment: could it have anything to do with the way `toString()` converts the map? I updated the question to include the string that gets stored in the DB

Answer (score 1):

Edit #2:

So apparently there is no "safe" way to convert that string back to a map without something custom. I would recommend saving the structure in the database as it originally comes in. If you can do that, then all you would need is `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Doing that doesn't work in part due to the nature of how things are passed. Groovy takes the JSON that is sent in and creates the params object. I here (I think) it strips off the "" on empty strings. When I  use `JSON.parse()`, I get an error when it gets to the first `,` after an empty item (ie: headMarkings)