# Change groovy variables inside shell executor in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline job where I am taking some build variables as input, and if the variables are not passed by the user, I execute a script and get the value of those variables. Later I have to use the value of these variables to trigger other jobs.

So my code looks something like this:

```
node {
withCredentials([[$class: 'StringBinding', credentialsId: 'DOCKER_HOST', variable: 'DOCKER_HOST']]) {

env.T_RELEASE_VERSION = T_RELEASE_VERSION
env.C_RELEASE_VERSION = C_RELEASE_VERSION
env.N_RELEASE_VERSION = N_RELEASE_VERSION
env.F_RELEASE_VERSION = F_RELEASE_VERSION

....

stage concurrency: 1, name: 'consul-get-version'
sh '''
        if [ -z ${T_RELEASE_VERSION} ]
        then
            export T_RELEASE_VERSION=$(ruby common/consul/services_prod_version.rb prod_t_release_version)
            aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1
            aws ecr list-images --repository-name t-server | grep ${T_RELEASE_VERSION}
        else
            aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1
            aws ecr list-images --repository-name t-server | grep ${T_RELEASE_VERSION}
        fi

.......


    't-integ-pipeline' : {
build job: 't-integ-pipeline', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'RELEASE_VERSION', value: T_RELEASE_VERSION],
                                           [$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'FASTFORWARD_TO_DEPLOY', value: true]]
},

......
```

The issue is when I am triggering the main job with empty T_RELEASE_VERSION, the child build job t-integ-pipeline is triggered with an empty value of the RELEASE_VERSION parameter.

How can I change a groovy parameter inside a shell executor and then access it again in the groovy executor with the modified value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using env-inject it was possible to store the values in the properties files and the inject them as environment variables. Couldn't find any easy way to do it in pipeline.

Here is a solution anyway, store the values to a file, and read the file from the pipeline. Then use eval or similar to transform it to an parsable object (hash).

Eval.me example: [Serializing groovy map to string with quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267836/serializing-groovy-map-to-string-with-quotes)

Write/Read to file example:
https://wilsonmar.github.io/jenkins2-pipeline/

EDIT
Manish solution for readability:

```
sh 'ruby common/consul/services_prod_version.rb prod_n_release_version > status' 
N_RELEASE_VERSION_NEW = readFile('status').trim() 
sh 'ruby common/consul/services_prod_version.rb prod_q_release_version > status' 
Q_RELEASE_VERSION_NEW = readFile('status').trim()
```

Comment: I utilized your suggestion and came up with something like this :         sh 'ruby common/consul/services_prod_version.rb prod_n_release_version > status'
        N_RELEASE_VERSION_NEW = readFile('status').trim()

        sh 'ruby common/consul/services_prod_version.rb prod_q_release_version > status'
        Q_RELEASE_VERSION_NEW = readFile('status').trim()

Comment: Great, adding the way you solved to my answer, just for readability

Answer (score 0):

I found a way change the groovy variable in the shell, No need to store it in the file, There is a example here [git-tag-message-plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-tag-message/#user-content-pipeline), I use this method like below:

```
script{
N_RELEASE_VERSION_NEW = getN_RELEASE_VERSION_NEW()
}


String getN_RELEASE_VERSION_NEW() {
    return sh(script: "ruby common/consul/services_prod_version.rb prod_n_release_version ", returnStdout: true)?.trim()
}
```