# How to export a variable from sh to groovy in a jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sh

How is it possible to export a variable from the sh context of sh context to the groovy context of the jenkins pipline job?

Pipeline Code:

```
node {
   echo 'Hello World'
   sh 'export VERSION="v$(date)"'
   echo env.VERSION
}
```

outupt:

```
[Pipeline] sh
[test-pipeline] Running shell script
++ date
+ export 'VERSION=vThu Dec  1 12:14:40 CET 2016'
+ VERSION='vThu Dec  1 12:14:40 CET 2016'
[Pipeline] echo`enter code here`
null
```

i am using Jenkins ver. 2.34

**update:**
there is the possibility to write the variable to a temporary file and read it later. This looks totally like a hack to me. It is not "thread-safe" by default when using parallel builds and does not scale if you need to export multiple variable in one run. Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40629924/change-groovy-variables-inside-shell-executor-in-jenkins-pipeline/40637578#40637578

Comment: thanks, yes this is something similar i wanted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this will help.

```
node('master'){
    stage('stage1'){
    def commit = sh (returnStdout: true, script: '''echo hi
    echo bye | grep -o "e"
    date
    echo lol''').split()



    echo "${commit[-1]} "

    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. But god I hate that syntax. Is passing the script string in `(script:)` required, or can this just be `sh """<script>"""` ?